# PHP preg_replace img that contains specific string inside src element

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace any html image tag that contains a specific string inside the "src" attribute.

Example:

```
<img id="IMG1" src="cid:image001.jpg@01CFA26C.40AE5BD0"/>
```

Should be replaced with "SOME STRING".

Images that contain a valid URL must not be replaced:

```
<img id="IMG1" src="http://someurl/image.png"/>
```

Can someone help me getting the correct regular expression for that?

EDIT:
This one is my basic example but it replaces every image tag. I tried to get it on my own but unfortunately it didn't work:

```
preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "SOME STRING", $myBaseString)
```

Thanks a lot.

Philip

Comment: What is the "specific string inside  "src" attribute"?

Comment: I think to search for **cid:** would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex:

```
(<img\b\s+.*?src=\")(.*?cid:.*?)(\">)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1SOME STRING\3
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/37)